# Query remaining field names from a database table

Tags: 8, entities

There's a database table. I know only one field name on the database table: username. How do I view  remaining field names on the table?

```
namespace Drupal\fixx_helper\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class AutocompleteController extends ControllerBase
{
   public function handleAutocomplete(Request $request)
   {
      $results = [];

      $input = $request->query->get('q');
      $database = \Drupal::database();
      $my_query = $database->query("select distinct username from banner_exports.ws_students where username like '$input%'");


      while($result = $my_query->fetchAssoc()){
         $matches[] = array('value' => $result['username'], 'label' => $result['username']);
       }
       return new JsonResponse($matches);
```

}}

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple table locations for Drupal field data: the base [User entity](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/class/User/9.0.x)
table `users_field_data` & the `user__$FIELD` tables that contain the custom fields defined by site builder / developer. If you need *field data* from a DB query, then you're going to need to build a query with a few joins to put it all together.

If you're only looking for the field names then it's much earlier to use the entity field manager to pull the base & custom fields:

```
\Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('user', 'user')
```